# How to make CSS shaped button/border?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Please, can you give me tips on how to make shaped button/menu navigation?
It should look like this:

[image: menu items]

I have tried something with borders, but it's working only if there is no text inside the `div`.

Here is the code I tried:

```
.border-right {
  font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 50px solid #93D1C1;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #4F4135;
  border-left: 50px solid #93D1C1;
  border-right: 50px solid #93D1C1;
}
```

[It looks like this (Codepen)](https://codepen.io/vlastapolach/pen/mwybBO)

Any ideas, please?

Comment: you need to use :after and :before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgNbvV

```
body {
  background-color: #4F4135;
}
.border-right {
  font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 50px solid #93D1C1;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #4F4135;
  border-left: 50px solid #93D1C1;
  border-right: 50px solid #93D1C1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.border-wrong {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #93D1C1;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.border-wrong:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #93D1C1;
  border-top: 25px solid #93D1C1;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #4F4135;
  border-left: 50px solid #93D1C1;
  border-right: 50px solid #93D1C1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's it. Thank you so much!